# proxy.pac - using regexp to proxy site root but not subfolders

Tags: regex, internet-explorer, proxy, proxy.pac

I have a bit of a strange request in that I am trying to use a proxy.pac file to use a proxy server for the following:

```
www.domain.com
www.domain.xx.xx
www.domain.com/?foo=1&bar=1  (where foo/bar can be any querystring)
```

but not:

```
www.domain.com/folder/
subdom.domain.com
```

I have tried the following but it did not appear to work when testing:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    if (shExpMatch(url, "www.domain.*/?*")) return "PROXY 1.2.3.4:1234";
    return "DIRECT";
}
```

Comment: does the domain name you don't want to match contains the string `folder`?

Comment: No, folder was just an example unfortunately

Comment: then how we differentiate these two strings, `www.domain.com/?foo=1&bar=1`, `www.domain.com/folder/`

Comment: One is prefixed with a question mark after the domain name?

Comment: Forget that approach.  If you find an interesting domain, split the URL in parts (e.g. protocol, address, port, path, query string) and decide with those pieces to which proxy you want to redirect, if at all.  I'm not saying it's impossible with regexps, just that it won't be easy to understand later, and as a consequence, not easily maintainable.